# Help installing on Asus eeePad 1025c

Tags: installation, 12.10, asus

This is in regards to Ubuntu 12.10. I am not able to boot the live environment just gives me output then blanks out and stays at flashing cursor, I am however able to boot up the installer and connect to wifi and install the os no problem however it will not boot up and I'm not sure why is booting like normal printing out the list of starting services and what not then just stops and sits forever. I'm thinking it could be graphics related since the machine never starts X (i think). Any input will be greatly appreciated and I will be happy to provide more information to help solve the problem, thank you all.

Comment: Is it important to you to boot into the live environment? If you can get to the installer (which uses X, btw) just install it. Perhaps you'll be able to run it fine once it's fully installed.

Answer (score 0):

[Asus 1025c](http://www.asus.com/Eee/Eee_PC/Eee_PC_1025C/#specifications) is a CedarView based netbook, which are [known to boot to black screen](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1069031) both with 12.04 and 12.10.

IMHO, 12.10 is a bit heavy for a netbook anyway. Try 12.04, with Unity2d or another lightweight environment, and follow the [Poulsbo wiki](to work around the black screen problem).

Basically, if hit with a black screen when booting from USB, press `ctrl-alt-f1` to switch to a tty, log in, and restart xserver with

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

After the installation, run `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`, and add `console=tty1` to the following line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

...the end result should look look like this

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash console=tty1"
```

Apply the GRUB configuration by running `sudo update-grub` (thanks to [user32674](https://askubuntu.com/users/32674/user32674) for pointing this out).

You could then also try searching for Additional Drivers in the Dash and install the CedarView driver.

Hope that works.